# How to investigate Java crash on OS X

Tags: java, macos, crash

We have a customer, who is experiencing native crashes in our Java SWT application on OS X. He is able to reproduce the problem using high-level action in the app, we are not.

We have a couple of crash logs from the customer, which seem to show that the crash occurs within OS code called by SWT. Also, they seem confusing to me, as they have different traces of crashed thread. Sample traces of crashed thread are pasted below.

*The question now is:* What I should look for in the crash logs, or what to try (ask customer to do) to gather more information to 'solve' the problem. And by 'solve' I mean either finding a way how to get rid of it, or isolating/reproducing it in such a way that it could be reported to wither SWT or Apple.

```
OS Version: Mac OS X 10.9.5 (13F34)

Crashed Thread: 0 Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGILL)
Exception Codes: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x000000010dbfb000
```

Trace Sample 1:

```
Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x00007fff8cebfa1a mach_msg_trap + 10
1 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x00007fff8cebed18 mach_msg + 64
2 com.apple.CoreGraphics 0x00007fff8d2ba99b _CGSSynchronizeWindowBackingStore + 97
3 com.apple.CoreGraphics 0x00007fff8d23c0cc _CGSLockWindow + 3765
4 com.apple.CoreGraphics 0x00007fff8d23afdf CGSDeviceLock + 240
5 libRIP.A.dylib 0x00007fff90616487 ripd_Lock + 43
6 libRIP.A.dylib 0x00007fff90616027 RIPLayerBltShape + 463
7 libRIP.A.dylib 0x00007fff90614468 ripc_Render + 304
8 libRIP.A.dylib 0x00007fff906102e1 ripc_DrawRects + 399
9 com.apple.CoreGraphics 0x00007fff8d23797a CGContextFillRects + 96
10 com.apple.AppKit 0x00007fff95a74c7f NSRectFill + 271
11 com.apple.AppKit 0x00007fff95b28ed8 -[NSScrollView drawRect:] + 473
12 libswt-pi-cocoa-4427.jnilib 0x0000000129f474ad Java_org_eclipse_swt_internal_cocoa_OS_objc_1msgSendSuper__Lorg_eclipse_swt_internal_cocoa_objc_1super_2JLorg_eclipse_swt_internal_cocoa_NSRect_2 + 186
```

Trace Sample 2:

```
Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8baf6a1a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8baf5d18 mach_msg + 64
2   com.apple.CoreGraphics          0x00007fff8bee9dd0 _CGSCopyWindowsWithOptionsAndTags + 144
3   com.apple.CoreGraphics          0x00007fff8bee9cfe __CGSCopyWindowsWithOptionsAndTags_block_invoke + 84
4   com.apple.CoreGraphics          0x00007fff8bee94cb array_call_as_integer_list + 267
5   com.apple.CoreGraphics          0x00007fff8bee9c60 CGSCopyWindowsWithOptionsAndTags + 253
6   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff94747f05 +[NSWindow _windowNumbersWithOptions:onSpace:] + 394
7   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff94747c03 -[NSApplication encodeRestorableStateWithCoder:] + 126
8   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff94744f23 -[NSPersistentUIRecord generateArchive:] + 170
9   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff9474580a recursivelyEncodeInvalidPersistentState + 421
10  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff94744115 -[NSPersistentUIManager flushAllChangesOptionallyWaitingUntilDone:updatingSnapshots:] + 1158
11  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff94743c58 -[NSPersistentUIManager flushPersistentStateAndClose:waitingUntilDone:] + 181
12  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff944fea66 run_cocoa_block + 41
13  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff948654d7 __29-[NSPersistentUIManager init]_block_invoke_2 + 77
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff944bc1bb _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff944b928d _dispatch_client_callout + 8
16  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff944c1433 _dispatch_after_timer_callback + 77
17  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff944b928d _dispatch_client_callout + 8
18  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff944bb885 _dispatch_source_invoke + 413
19  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff944c0e97 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 244
20  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8bc144f9 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
21  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8bbcf714 __CFRunLoopRun + 1636
22  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8bbcee75 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 309
23  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff95520a0d RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 226
24  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff955207b7 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 479
25  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff955205bc _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 65
26  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff9451e24e _DPSNextEvent + 1434
27  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff9451d89b -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 122
28  libswt-pi-cocoa-4427.jnilib     0x0000000120a4ed6a Java_org_eclipse_swt_internal_cocoa_OS_objc_1msgSendSuper__Lorg_eclipse_swt_internal_cocoa_objc_1super_2JJJJZ + 122
```

Comment: I would look at what is different. I.e. is it the version of the OS, or a shared library used, or the version of Java?  The trace suggests an issue in the OS, but this might be a side effect.

Comment: Thanks, @PeterLawrey. The JVM is bundled with our product, so it's same. The OS X is same AFAIK (10.9.5 with no pending updates).

Comment: I assume you bundle the SWT as well.  I would look through the list of shared libraries as something has to be different, unless it a bug which only occurs if you have more/less CPUs or a difference graphics card.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention we bundle SWT too. I was wondering if there are ways to find out what this mach_msg_trap method does. Or what data are involved. I suspect that it might be caused by different operation which corrupts memory and causes this crash (which I am investigating in parallel) - different traces seem to support this.